# using jenkins upload local file to ftp

Tags: jenkins, devops

I have been using jenkins for uploading a file from my local windows to ftp server used publish over ftp plugin the job shows succes  transfered file is 0 attached is the pic i get an error of 200[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v7HX.png) no file is transfered to ftp

Comment: Do the source and target directories exist? Does Jenkins have access to them? Are there any files in the source directory?

Comment: yes their is source and target file

Comment: Can you run the command successfully outside of Jenkins?

Comment: i am not using command using plugin

Comment: I know, but just for the sake of test try to run the command outside of Jenkins to see if the command succeeds so you can isolate the problem.

Comment: yes the command is working

Comment: Do you run the command with the same user that runs Jenkins?